# Frequency Distribution of data set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, distribution

I am trying to divide the following data set into 4 bins for my project.
Here is the data set of size 12. 
training data `set = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11]`

There are 12 elements so, to divide the data set into 4 bins I could divide it into bins with 3 data in each. 
I tried to use for loop, but here is the problem : 6 is twice. So, if I divide them using for loop '6' will be in to different bins which is not a correct method.

Is there any Matlab function to divide such data. 'histcounts' doesn't work since it is for equal width distribution.

Comment: Either you allow more than 3 values per bin, or allow for repeated values to be in different bins. You can't have both things at the same time

Comment: Is there any function available in matlab which does the frequency distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `histc`

```
[~, ib] = histc(set,[3:3:12]) %creation of index
bin = arrayfun(@(idx) set(ib == idx), unique(ib), 'UniformOutput', false) %split the array
```

:)